# how can I assert that a number goes or a list grows up in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

I have a TLA+ spec where I would like to assert that a list only ever grows in length (it's fine if it stays the same when stuttering.)

Right now I have something like this, but I'm certain that it's not right:

```
NoWorkIsLost == Len(samples) = Len(samples) ~> Len(samples) = Len(samples) + 1
```

I'm not even sure what to search for here, I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "the list only ever grows in length". The simplest way to do that would be to write

```
Op == [][Len(samples') > Len(samples)]_Len(samples)
```

But that's saying that *if the length changes*, the length must increase. That still allows for you to mutate the list without changing it! If you instead write

```
Op == [][Len(samples') > Len(samples)]_samples
```

Then you are saying that if `samples` changes, it must also increase in length. But this allows you to pop one element and push two in a single action. You probably want to express that the old sequence is a *prefix* of the new one. You can do that with

```
Op == [][SubSeq(samples', 1, Len(samples)) = samples]_samples
```